# Minted snippet with single quotes

Tags: minted, python

I want to create a Python's code snippet which includes single quotes using `minted` package. I've put it altogether like this:

```
\begin{minted}[
    autogobble,
    frame=lines,
    framesep=4mm,
    fontfamily=fdm,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    python3=true,
    style=vs]{python}
>>> D.mro()
[<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>,
<class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
\end{minted}
```

But the output does look a bit odd:

[image: Minted handling single quotes]

However changing single quotes to double quotes does not seem to work either. Does anyone know how to fix such behaviour? Thanks

Comment: Using `listings` doesn't lead to this issue so I think this is a bug of Pygments.

Comment: You're right, since the snippet represents the console output after the python's code execution, one workaround might be changing the language from `python` to `bash`.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36889/using-minted-with-mixed-python-code-and-output (in short: test the `pycon` lexer).

Comment: Just a warning: The `pycon` lexer does output different classifications so your chosen `vs` style will not work (in case you wonder why everything is black) ;)

Comment: Did the link I provided help you (may we close this as duplicate)?

Comment: I chose the the workaround switching to `bash` since the `vs` style does not work, but the link was useful, thanks